# Low level guy reincarnated by evil god

Tags: story-identification, manga

This story start out with the with someone being reincarnated. He is not reincarnated by a good god however, he is reincarnated by an evil god with a curse that only allows him to stay at, I believe, level 1. Also his maid turns out to be a couple hundred years old hero that has been waiting for him I believe.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/230070/manga-in-which-a-strong-magician-kept-reincarnating-so-that-he-could-finally-be - Note, not a dupe since the other question doesn't have an acceptance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [*Level 1 No Saikyou Kenja*](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/level-1-no-saikyou-kenja) (AKA *Level 1 Strongest Sage*).

> One day, Kijou Haruto was forcefully transmigrated and cursed by a god
> from another world. A world of swords and magic. In this world you get
> stronger by increasing your battle levels. But due to a curse, Haruto
> is unable to gain levels. However, due to a mistake by the Evil God,
> Haruto was able to obtain an inexhaustable supply of magic...

[image]