# Manga where a crest on hand determines how powerful you are

Tags: story-identification, manga

I do not remember much from this story at all but this is what I do remember. First our main character I believe is reincarnated but it is not the usual story. At the beginning of the story he is the strongest in the world and he has no one else to fight or get strong because of the crest he was born with being not for battle but for production. After he hit this bottle neck of not being able to go into the higher world to fight people he activates reincarnation magic and reincarnates.

He gets the new sigil which I believe is on his hand but in era the people who have the battle sigil are actually looked down upon because it take much more practice to start out but it overall more powerful. People believe that the sigil that start out very quickly is better but in reality it is weaker in the long run.

Comment: this could be 2 series. The one valorum describe and another 1 with a different plot that he is searching for comrade. He is at his peak even when reincarnate. 1st is a dragon loli. Both weakest crest for combat. He state that the spell he cast even with extreme optimize can't go under 0.5s but 3rd crest (specific for these spell) can cast it with just 0,1s without any pratice( Actually more than 10s by other people)

Comment: @someoneuseless What was the name of the other series if you know it since there are two that are very similar?

Comment: because there is also a similar manga i am looking for with the same type of story but they entered a diamond shaped structure in the desert which the mc created (when they entered it was at 20 something which was all their was for the manga at the time) before reincarnation created but that isn't enough info to make a new post. Also not sure if that specific part is in the manga below i have read through it but did not see what i just mentioned(Maybe i am just blind).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[Shikkakumon no Saikyou Kenja](https://myanimelist.net/anime/47161/Shikkakumon_no_Saikyou_Kenja)* (AKA *The Strongest Sage of Disqualified Crest*).

> In a world of magic, the powers and future of a mage are predetermined
> at birth through so-called "Marks"—four symbols that categorize a
> human's aptitude for magic. Lamenting the fact that his mark was
> considered ill-suited for combat and only useful for magic
> augmentation, an incredibly skilled sage decided to reincarnate
> thousands years in the future.
>
> Reborn as Mathias Hildesheimr—a six-year-old boy and the third son of
> a duke's family—he attains the mark of close combat he always desired.
> Unfortunately, it is also discovered that mankind's knowledge of magic
> and swordsmanship has drastically deteriorated in this era; only
> shoddy magic equipment can be sporadically found, while even the most
> basic spells have been forgotten. To add insult to injury, his current
> mark, once hailed as the most powerful, is now viewed as the worst.

[image]

Comment: Also the unaccepted answer to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/230070/manga-in-which-a-strong-magician-kept-reincarnating-so-that-he-could-finally-be?noredirect=1&lq=1